# PHP - preg_replace items in brackets with array items

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match-all

I have an array:

```
array('id' => 'really')
```

I have a string:

```
$string = 'This should be {id} simple.';
```

I want to end up with:

```
This should be really simple.
```

I have a regular expression that will work with the {id} aspect, but I am having a hard time doing what I want.

```
/{([a-zA-Z\_\-]*?)}/i
```

{id} could be anything, {foo} or {bar} or anything that matches my regular expression.

I am sure that there is a simple solution that is escaping me at the moment.

Thanks,

Justin

Comment: Ultimately, I'd refactor this whole task and leverage `vprintf()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

str_replace is faster then preg_replace, try this:

```
$arr = array('a' => 'a', 'b' => 'b');
$str = "{a} {b} {c}";
$values = array_values($arr);
$keys = array_keys($arr);

foreach ($keys as $k => $v) {
    $keys[$k] = '{'.$v.'}';
}

str_replace($keys, $values, $str);
```

Comment: This is true, but $arr (in your example) could have 100's of key/value pairs, I wonder if your solution would still be faster. Thanks.

Comment: maybe you can build the $arr in a way that it directly contains the '{' and '}? then you don't need the extra loop. But anyway.. it's still O(n) ;-) If you don't need fancy replacing rules , you should always use this function instead of ereg_replace() or preg_replace(). see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `preg_replace` with `e` modifier as:

```
$string = preg_replace('/{([a-zA-Z\_\-]*?)}/ie','$arr["$1"]',$string);
```

[**Ideone Link**](http://www.ideone.com/9cx4h)

Using the `e` modifier you can have any PHP *expression* in the replacement part of `preg_replace`.

Now why did your regex `/{([a-zA-Z\_\-])*?}/i` not work?

You've put `*?` outside the capturing parenthesis `( )` as a result you capture only the first character of the word found in `{  }`.

Also note that you've not escaped `{` and `}` which are regex meta-character used for specifying range quantifier `{num}`, `{min,max}`. But in your case there is *no need* to escape them because the regex engine can infer from the context that `{` and `}` cannot be used as range operator as they are not having numbers in required format inside them and hence treats them literally.

Comment: thanks for the updates to my regex and the other helpful hints.  Silly mistake really.  Thanks, again.

Comment: \e modifier is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) as of v5.5

Comment: Please update this unusable snippet.  `e` doesn't work. `i` doesn't make sense. Underscores don't need to be escaped in a character class. The ideone links is dead.

Answer (score 1):

[`preg_replace_callback`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) has a callback option which make that kind of things possible.

```
function replaceText($matches){
  global $data;
  return $data[$matches[1]];
}
preg_replace_callback(
        '/{([a-zA-Z\_\-])*?}/i',
        'replaceText',
        $content
);
```

If you don't want to use the global variable create an class and use the `array($object, 'method')` callback notation.

Comment: Thanks.  I forgot about preg_replace_callback.

Comment: The `i` flag is useless because you have written `a-zA-Z`.  `_` doesn't need to be escaped inside of a character class.